# Remove line on notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

My test data:

```
- sample text
- text text
- sample sample
- test sample text
- test text
- § text
- Ø sample
sample text
text text
sample sample
§
Ø
```

I want to delete all lines starting with "-" and containing [sample,test,§,Ø]. The result should be:

```
- text text
sample text
text text
sample sample
test sample text
test text
§
Ø
```

I have tried `^- .*sample,test,[^\x00-\x7F]+.*\R?` but it didn't work. I need to merge `^- .*sample.*\R?`, `^- .*test.*\R?` and `^- .*[^\x00-\x7F]+.*\R?`. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get?

Comment: Please, never post code in comment, it's unreadable, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64913564/edit) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You want to match all lines that contain either of the words or characters and match the newline sequences at the end.

Note that `- test sample text` starts with `-` and contains test so that will also be removed.

```
^-.*?(?:\bsample\b|\btest\b|[§Ø]).*\R*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `-.*?` Match `-` followed by as least chars as possible without a newline
- `(?:\bsample\b|\btest\b|[§Ø])` Match either `sample` `test` `§` or `Ø`
- `.*\R*` Match the rest of the line and optional newline sequence

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nqvbFX/1)

If there should at least be a single space after the hyphen, you could also match 1 or more horizontal whitespace characters `\h+`

```
^-\h+.*?(?:\bsample\b|\btest\b|[§Ø]).*\R*
```

[image]

Comment: "Match `=` followed by...": is that a typo?  Do you mean `-` or `=`?  I'm trying to understand the regex for my own edification.

Comment: @Marc That is a type, sharp!

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
^-.*(sample|test|§|Ø).*$
```

and it gave me what I believe to be a correct answer.
I am not 100% sure since there is inconsistency between the top snippet to the bottom. For example, "test text" appears in results but not in the target text.

Comment: thanks for answering, but the code does not remove the line